# Android: Resizing the gallery items

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

I'm using `Gallery` in my project. The features I want are listed below:

1. There should be 5 images visible at a time on the screen.
2. Number of images can increase or decrease dynamically.
3. The center image or we can say the selected image should be larger than rest of the four images.(0,1,[2],3,4).
4. The neighbouring images of center one should be smaller than the selected image but lagrer than the images at the corners.(0,[1],2,[3],4).
5. The images at the corners of the screen should be smaller than from rest of the images.

I don't know how to implenent this. I have channged the size of the center `ImageView` but I dont know how to set the size of rest of the four images. Please provide solution to this problem.

Here's my code for changing the size of ImageView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

public class InfiniteGalleryResourceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
/** The width of each child image */
private static final int G_ITEM_WIDTH = 60;
/** The height of each child image */
private static final int G_ITEM_HEIGHT = 250;


/** The context your gallery is running in (usually the activity) */
private Context mContext;
private int imageWidth;
private int imageHeight;
/** The array of resource ids to draw */
private final int[] imageIds;

public InfiniteGalleryResourceAdapter(Context c, int[] imageIds ) {

    this.mContext = c;
    this.imageIds = imageIds;
}

/**
 * The count of how many items are in this Adapter
 * This will return the max number as we want it to scroll as much as possible
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convertView is always null in android.widget.Gallery


    ImageView i = getImageView();
    int itemPos = (position % imageIds.length);

    try {
        // first we calculate the item position in your list, because we have said the adapters size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
        // the position getView gives us is not use-able in its current form, we have to use the modulus operator
        // to work out what number in our 'array of paths' this actually equals
        Log.d("item position", String.valueOf(itemPos));

        i.setImageResource(imageIds[itemPos]);
        ((BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable()).setAntiAlias(true); // Make sure we set anti-aliasing otherwise we get jaggies (non-smooth lines)

    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // a 'just in case' scenario
        Log.e("InfiniteGalleryResourceAdapter", "Out of memory creating imageview. Using empty view.", e);
    }

    return i;
}

/**
 * Retrieve an ImageView to be used with the Gallery
 * @return an ImageView with width and height set to DIP values
 */
private ImageView getImageView() {
    setImageDimensions();

    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight));
    i.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    return i;
}

/**
 * Sets the dimensions for each View that is used in the gallery
 * lazily initialized so that we don't have to keep converting over and over
 */
private void setImageDimensions() {
    if (imageWidth == 0 || imageHeight == 0) {
        imageWidth = AndroidUtils.convertToPix(mContext, G_ITEM_WIDTH);
        imageHeight = AndroidUtils.convertToPix(mContext, G_ITEM_HEIGHT);
    }
}
}
```